# Compiling dojo into a single build file

Tags: compilation, dojo

Does any one has idea to compile a dojo into a single file. I am trying to host the project into a website, and dojo has 100's of files to be uploaded.. if any one got idea. please share.

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/build/

Answer (score 1):

As addition to the answer of Craig of following the [build tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/build/), I also want to add that there's a [web builder](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/) that can help you with it.

With this tool you can specify the modules you need and create a single JavaScript file of it.

Comment: but Dimitri M .. With web builder how can I add a third party module like dGrid for example??

Comment: Then you will probably need to manually create a build using the build totorial provided by Craig.